# changing location of App_Data and ASPNET.MDF database

Tags: asp.net, database, login-control

I have a bit noobish question, so please forgive me, as I don't have much experience with asp.net.

I have created login control, which uses automatically generated ASPNET.MDF which is located in the App_Data folder.

Connection string looks like this:
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"

Now, I would like to place App_Data folder in db folder so database would be in db/App_Data/ASPNET.MDF. How do I change connection string to reflect this.

Thanks you for help

Answer (score 0):

Go into the IIS management of your production machine, and open the IIS, then:

- Press on ConnectionStrings (it will give you a list of all of the connection strings in your site)
- Alter the connection string of `localserver` to be similar to:

```
    (data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;DataSource=db/App_Data/ASPNET.MDF;User Instance=true)
```